# XNA Game Studio 4.0 in VS2010 Express Installation Issues

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna

I am try to get the 4.0 up and running in VS 2010, I downloaded, I installed, I launched VS2010 following the instructions at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203893.aspx. I click file new project and look under C# and lo and behold there is nothing what-so-ever to do with XNA listed there.

Can someone tell me how to get the XNA templates to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer although I am not entirely happy about it, but what are you going to do. You have to launch the VS 2010 Express for Windows Phone it is not integrated into my other VS2010 installation.

Comment: Are you sure? I have Game Studio 4.0 installed, and it shows up integrated into my regular VS 2010 Ultimate install: http://imgur.com/ciAOn.jpg

Comment: I am using the VS2010 Express, there must be a difference because I cannot get it to load. It does load in the VS 2010 for windows phone development so I actually have two separate VS installs which is just kind of silly if you ask me.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure when you start a new project that the target Framework is set to 4.0... i noticed something similar the other day and had no templates listed under XNA, then realized I had compiled my last project using 2.0 framework and Visual Studio had remembered that... switched to 4.0 and then the templates showed properly.